# stop a 3D array from being flattened after apply

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I am running an apply on a 3D array, and it is returning a 2D array

```
m = replace(array(1:16,dim=c(4,2,2)), c(1,13,14), NA)
dim(m)
# [1] 4 2 2
```

I want to replace, for each slice, the NAs of that slice with the average value (again for that slice), for the above matrix with 4 entries in the first dimension, here are there means:

```
apply(m,1,function(x) mean(x,na.rm = T))
# [1]  7  6  9 10
```

This is the function that I want to use to do the replacing:

```
replace_na_with_mean = function(a){ 
  a[is.na(a)] = mean(a, na.rm = T); 
  #print(dim(a)); 
  return(a)
}
```

This is the desired result:

```
# out[1,,] should have 7s instead of it's NAs
# out[2,,] should have 6s instead of it's NAs
# out[3,,] should have 9s instead of it's NAs
# out[4,,] should have 10s instead of it's NAs
```

This works:

```
out = m
for(i in 1:dim(m)[1]){
  out[i, , ] = replace_na_with_mean(m[i, , ])
}
# here is the working output:
# > m[1,,]
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA    9
# [2,]    5   NA
# > out[1,,]
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    7    9
# [2,]    5    7
```

But I cant get it done with apply.

```
out = m
out[] = apply(m,1,replace_na_with_mean)
# this is the failing output:
# > m[1,,]
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA    9
# [2,]    5   NA
# > out[1,,]
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    7    3
# [2,]    2    4
```

Comment: Can you please add a reproducable example?

Comment: try `out <- m ; out[] = apply(m, 1, replace_na_with_mean)`

Comment: @user2957945 - OP might want to clarify what the result they want is - `apply(m,1,FUN)` on a 3 dimensional array gives different results to what you might expect. i.e. - try it on `m <- replace(array(1:16,dim=c(4,2,2)), c(1,13,14), NA)` for instance.

Comment: I tried the `out[]` solution. It maintains the array shape, but is doing something really weird. its replacing values that are not `NA` and replacing them with weird values too.

Comment: `?apply` "In all cases the result is coerced by as.vector to one of the basic vector types before the dimensions are set". This means even though your function returns an array, it is turned into a vector before being used to fill your `out` array. That's where the scrambling is occurring.